# Information on Horseshoe Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request

I was watching the following [video](https://youtu.be/j4hW7AwETZA) (around 2:56), and he mentioned "horseshoe mathematics/horseshoe integration", though I was unable to find any information on what this is. If someone know's more about the topic could you perhaps provide some resources to learn more about it?

Thanks

Comment: At what point in the video is this mentioned?

Comment: This is MSE. For information about videos, you better ask at youtube.

Comment: Don't take that video seriously. It's *humor*!

Comment: Finding antiderivatives is freshman level stuff. Most antiderivatives do not have nice closed forms. Instead you calculate them by numerical methods (actually, other than rational functions, you calculate those "nice closed forms" by numerical methods, too). His "professor" would be pitied, not celebrated, for wasting 20 years on such a problem. The "horseshoe" is just the trivial fact that everything is equal to itself. True, but of no real use.

Comment: the horseshoe is when you draw that a thing is equal to itself, so it's a joke because it resembles a horseshoe.

Comment: Horseshoe integration is integration using semicircular contours, like this: https://qr.ae/TSkU0u This question should be reopened.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

this is a joke video, there is no such thing as horseshoe integration.

Comment: Horseshoe integration is integration using semicircular contours, like this: https://qr.ae/TSkU0u This question should be reopened.

Comment: It’s still a joke @Anixx they obviously weren’t doing semicircular contour integration. That is a definite method, not an antiderivative-finding method

Answer (score 32):

It's simple, any integrals can be solved by drawing a horseshoe, even the toughest ones! The horseshoe is simply that powerful!

Comment: Yes. Horseshoe integration is integration using semicircular contours, like this: https://qr.ae/TSkU0u This question should be reopened.