# How to evaluate the integral of $\int\sin(\sin(x))dx$?

Tags: integration

I recently watched a video on YouTube talking about something called as horseshoe integrals. A bit of research told me that that's not really a thing.

Nonetheless, the YouTuber referred to the integral 
$$
\int\sin(\sin(x))dx
$$
to be an example of a horseshoe integral and I haven't been able to come to a solution.

Any leads would help.

Comment: I think it can't be expressed in terms of standard functions.

Comment: Best you could do is a series approximation.

Comment: What is the YouTube video?

Comment: I think it's this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503401/information-on-horseshoe-integration

Comment: I think the term *horseshoe integral* is a tongue-in-cheek reference to the fact that there's no elementary representation of that function other than $\int \sin(\sin x)\,dx$.  It is what it is, a function whose derivative is $\sin(\sin(x))$.  The equals sign bends back.

Comment: I think you've been bamboozled.

Comment: This can be integrated but would be in the form of an infinite series. If that's the answer you want then i can type it out for you.

Comment: The video is a joke; watch it again, if you must ;)

Comment: The first few terms in the series expansion of the integral is $\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{12}+\frac{x^6}{60}-\frac{x^8}{315}+O(x^9)+C$ using wolfram alpha. Also, the definite integral from $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}H_0(1)$ where $H_n(x)$ is a [Struve Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StruveFunction.html).

Comment: I have watched the video I think this came from, it is satire talking about the further you get into maths the more problems have non-elementary solutions

Comment: $$\int\sin(\sin(x))dx=\Im\int e^{j\sin(x)}dx=\Im\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{j^n\sin^n(x)}{n!}dx$$ Is also possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int \sin (\sin (x))dx $ cannot be expressed in the form of elementary functions. If you still want to integrate it, you can do so using the infinite series of $\sin(x)$.

$$\sin(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} $$

$$\int \sin (\sin (x))dx=\int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(\sin x)^{2n+1} dx$$
Since  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}$ converges to $\sin(1)$ we can swap the integral sign with the summation.

$$\int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(\sin x)^{2n+1} dx=  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \int(\sin x)^{2n+1} dx$$

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \int(\sin x)^{2n+1} dx=$$
$$-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\cos(x)\sin^{2n}(x)sin^{2}(x)^{-n} 2F_1(1/2, -n; 3/2 ; cos^2(x))+C$$

where, $_2F_1 (a,b ;c;d)$ is the [hyper geometric function.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html)